# Are parametrizations of regular surfaces local diffeomorphisms?

Tags: geometry

Say we have a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a parametrization of this surface $x: U\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$. That is to say,

1. $x$ is a smooth homeomorphism.
2. For all $p \in U$, $dx_p$ is injective.

Is $x$ a local diffeomorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how you define a "parametrization". The point is that the Jacobian matrix should have maximal rank, namely, the rank of $\left(\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial u^j}\right)_{i=1,2,3;\; j=1,2}$ has to be 2. To avoid wild behavior at the boundary, assume the same condition on a compact set.

Without the compactness assumption, you can run into problems such as an irrational-slope line on a torus. The latter can be embedded in $R^3$ and therefore you get a map from the line to $R^3$ which satisfies your conditions but is not a local diffeomorphism because with the topology induced from $R^3$ it is not locally connected (the same can be done with a surface in place of a line).

Comment: You have a typo in your Jacobian determinant :) The condition that $x$ is a homeomorphism to its image (note to OP: you need to say that) rules out phenomena analogous to the dense line on the torus one dimension down. So the "homeomorphism" hypothesis rules out topological problems. And an application of the inverse function theorem will say that $x$ is a local diffeomorphism to its image. (A map with injective derivative looks locally like the inclusion of $U\subset\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3$ as a linear subspace.)